# I can access static methods, but not instantiable ones

Tags: c#, .net, class

Well, plain and simple: I can access static methods, but not instantiable ones.

At first I thought it was a problem that extended to all classes but this has puzzled me even more. Let me illustrate with an example.

I have a public SQLQueries class with two test methods. Banana() is static and Orange() is not. Both are public and the class itself is public.

[Declaration](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mtIrD.png)

```
    public class SQLQueries
    {
        public static string Banana()
        {
            return "Banana";
        }
       
       public string Orange()
        {
            return "Orange";
        }
    }
```

I go to another class library (SQLProcedures) file in the same namespace (DatabaseBehaviour). I create an instance of the class and I am given for good, in fact the SQLQueries class name is recognized and I can even peek the definition.

[Errors](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SONQj.png)

As I expected, the static method Banana() works if I call directly from the class and I get an error if I try to do it through the "ey" instance I created.

However, and this is what puzzles me, Orange() does not work in either case and gives me this message at the code that should be working.

[Message error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AkFDx.png)

```
    public class SQLProcedures
    {

        SQLQueries ey = new SQLQueries();

        string a = SQLQueries.Banana();
        string b = ey.Banana();

        string c= SQLQueries.Orange();
        string d= ey.Orange();

    }
```

To make sure that it is not a problem of my classes in particular, I have tried to create the Dictionary that eventually will be in SQLQueries and once again the same thing: I can create the instance but not access its methods as .Add()

```
    public class SQLProcedures
    {
        Dictionary<string, string> queriesAdd = new Dictionary<string, string>();
        Dictionary<string, string> queriesRemove = new Dictionary<string, string>();
        Dictionary<string, string> queriesUpdate = new Dictionary<string, string>();

    }
```

[Dictionary test](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Va1TM.png)

Right now the only hypothesis I have is that somehow the type of project that contains both files (a .NET Framework 4 type class library) is affecting them in some way that completely escapes me. But I recognize that it is something very adventurous that is not based on anything.

What could be going on? 0.0''

Many thanks to all who kindly give me a moment of their time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is you need to be in a method.

The error says that "A field initializer...". This is because `d` (and abc) are fields.

Create a method and it will work fine:

```cs
public class SQLProcedures
{
    public void M()
    {

        SQLQueries ey = new SQLQueries();

        string a = SQLQueries.Banana();
        string b = ey.Banana();

        string c= SQLQueries.Orange();
        string d= ey.Orange();
    }
}
```

There are limitations on what you can do with field initilizers, if you want to initlilize something complex as part of you class, use a constructor.

Part of the problem is the order in which the code will run and how .NET initilizers field.

Comment: You nail it man, thank you so much <3

Comment: Always read error messages, (and then search for them if you don't understand them) :)

Comment: I did but for some reason my brain wasn't able to put the pieces together. I guess the dullness of having been at it for a long time.

Answer (score 1):

To access the non-static method of a non-static class, you must instantiate the object. Create an instance of object in an executable code

```
var query = new SQLQueries();
query.Orange();
```

Answer (score 1):

In C# field initializers cannot reference other instance variables.

Field initializers are variables declared directly inside the class like `a`, `b`, `c` and `d` are. The variable `c` will never work, not even inside a method since and object reference is required to access the non-static `Orange` method. The `b` variable will also never work since you cannot access static methods from an instance.

The reason the `d` variable doesn't work is quite interesting. After reading about this for a while I stumbled across a few answers saying that the C# compiler might rearrange the order of field instantiation thus there is no guarantee that `SQLQueries` will be instantiated before `d` which could throw a `NullReferenceException`. This is absolutely not true.

The example for [Compiler Error CS0236](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/misc/cs0236?f1url=%3FappId%3Droslyn%26k%3Dk(CS0236)) on the Microsoft Documentation is as follows

```
public class MyClass
{
    public int i = 5;

    // To fix the error, remove "= i", and uncomment the line in constructor.
    public int j = i;  // CS0236

    public MyClass()
    {
        // Uncomment the following.
        //j = i;
    }
}
```

Just like the other answers they recommend moving the instantiation inside the class constructor, but it doesn't explain why this error happens.

Classes start their existence when the constructor ends its execution, and in C# the constructors logic is executed last, therefore when the field `j` references the other field `i` it is referencing `i` from the class itself, and since the class does not exist yet compiler error CS0236 happens. To quote The C# Language Specification section 10.5.5.2 `A variable initializer for an instance field cannot reference the instance being created`.

But the real reason this error happens is because the designers of C# wanted it this way. This error does not occur in Java for example, you can even access static methods from an instance in Java but it does give a warning.

Answer (score 0):

For `static` methods (`Banana()`), you can only use the Class Name, not an instance name.

For the instance methods (`Orange()`), you need to move them to either the constructor, or some point later in the code, like a method:

```
public class SQLProcedures
{

    SQLQueries ey = new SQLQueries();

    string a = SQLQueries.Banana();
    string b = null;

    public SQLProcedures()
    {
        b = ey.Orange();
    }

}
```